# Filtering a Pandas DataFrame through a list dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

[Movie Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3srA.png)

I have a DataFrame that contains movie information and I'm trying to filter the rows so that if the list of dictionaries contains 'name' == 'specified genre' it will display movies containing that genre.

I have tried using a list comprehension

```
filter = ['Action']
expectedResult = [d for d in df if d['name'] in filter]
```

however I end up with an error:

*TypeError: string indices must be integers*

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data and expected output (no images)? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d is a column name in your code. That's why you are getting this error.

See the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"abc": [1,2,3], "def": [4,5,6]})
for d in df:
    print(d)
```

Gives:

```py
abc
def
```

I think what you are trying to do could be achieved by:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"genre": ["something", "soemthing else"], "abc": ["movie1", "movie2"]})

movies = df.to_dict("records")

[m["abc"] for m in movies if m["genre"] == "something"]
```

Which gives:

```py
['movie1']
```

Answer (score 0):

your loop,`for d in df`, will give the headings for your values.
your d will have generes as a value.
try to run:-

```
for d in df:
    print(d)
```

you will understand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! This is better placed as a comment rather than an answer. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @algometrix consider flagging this as a comment / low quality answer rather than editing it to help newer users.